# ERROR Error: No provider for JwtHelper

Tags: angular, authentication, web, jwt

I'm new to Angular2 and i'm using jwthelper to encode the jwt token and extract the details.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { JwtHelper } from 'angular2-jwt';

@Injectable()
export class SessionService {

  constructor(private jwtHelper: JwtHelper){}

  getUser(){
    var token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    return this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(token.token);
  }
}
```

Couldn't find a solution for the following error and show me what is incorrect here.

> ERROR Error: No provider for JwtHelper!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is because you are trying to inject `JwtHelper` in the constructor of your component/service. This is done *only for providers*.

According to [using jwthelper in components](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt#using-jwthelper-in-components) section, you have to create a new object and use it.

In your service,

```
constructor(){} //remove from constructor.

  getUser(){
    let jwtHelper: JwtHelper = new JwtHelper();
    var token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    return this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(token.token);
  }
```

Comment: Is this the most efficient way of using jwthelper in a service?

Comment: Check [here](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/blob/master/angular2-jwt.ts#L207) It is just an exported class without any decorators..

Comment: Now i can understand.